# Facebook SDK for Unity v7.0.3 FB.Init delegate never called

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I was using Facebook SDK for Unity v7.0.2 without problem. Once I updated to 7.0.3 I noticed that the call back delegate fro FB.Init is never called on the device or in the editor.

Of course after updating I had to make changes because of the breaking updates  in 7.0.3 like IResult. But I didn't change anything other than the breaking stuff.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: I think there is a problem about the sdk. There is no callback on example project too.

Comment: Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a confirmed bug from facebook new sdk.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/723910167712942/